# Using a loop to calculate correlation based on subset data in R

Tags: r, correlation

I have a large dataset with several products in one column and information on each product including unit retail and quantity by week for the previous several years. I am trying to write a for loop that subsets the data by product name and calculates the correlation between unit retail and quantity for the number of rows for each product.

I have been able to subset the data based on product and calculate the correlation, but there are many products and it would be more beneficial to implement a loop to go through each unique product.

Example of dataset:

```
`Category Label` `Fiscal Year`     `Fiscal Week`               `Net Sales` `Extended Quantity`    `Unit Retail`         `Log QTY`            `Log Retail`
   <chr>             <chr>             <chr>                        <dbl>             <dbl>            <dbl>           <dbl>            <dbl>
 1 LOOSE CITRUS      FY2018            FY2018-P01-W1              170833.           204901.            0.834            12.2           -0.182
 2 LOOSE CITRUS      FY2018            FY2018-P01-W2              158609.           187650.            0.845            12.1           -0.168
 3 LOOSE CITRUS      FY2018            FY2018-P01-W3              163580.           196313.            0.833            12.2           -0.182
 4 LOOSE CITRUS      FY2018            FY2018-P01-W4              146240.           185984.            0.786            12.1           -0.240
 5 LOOSE CITRUS      FY2018            FY2018-P02-W1              147494.           171036.            0.862            12.0           -0.148
 6 LOOSE ONIONS      FY2018            FY2018-P01-W1               88802.            78446.             1.13            11.3            0.124
 7 LOOSE ONIONS      FY2018            FY2018-P01-W2               77365.            66898.             1.16            11.1            0.145
 8 LOOSE ONIONS      FY2018            FY2018-P01-W3               88026.            75055.             1.17            11.2            0.159
 9 LOOSE ONIONS      FY2018            FY2018-P01-W4              114720.            97051.             1.18            11.5            0.167
10 LOOSE ONIONS      FY2018            FY2018-P02-W1               95746.            82128.             1.17            11.3            0.153
```

```
#subset data into own df based on category
allProduce_split <- split(allProduce, allProduce$`Category Label`)

#correlation
cor_produce <- cor(allProduce_split$LOOSE CITRUS$`Unit Retail`, 
                   allProduce_split$LOOSE CITRUS$`Extended Quantity`)
```

Rather than just return the correlation for the "LOOSE CITRUS' product in the example, I am hoping to have a table that contains single row for each product name with the correlation between unit retail and quantity for all 5 fiscal weeks. For example:

```
'Category Label'     'Cor'
LOOSE CITRUS          .5363807
LOOSE ONIONS          .6415218
product C             .6498723
Product D             -.451258
Product E             .0012548
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider `by` which is similar to `split` but then allows any function to be applied on the subsets using a third argument. In your case, your function can build a data frame of product label and correlation result:

```
df_list <- by(allProduce, allProduce$`Category Label`, function(sub)
    data.frame(product = sub$Category_Label[1],
               cor_produce = cor(sub$`Unit Retail`,
                                 sub$`Extended Quantity`)
               )
)

final_df <- do.call(rbind, unname(df_list))
```

Alternatively, you can still use the `split` but then run an `lapply`:

```
allProduce_split <- split(allProduce, allProduce$`Category Label`)

df_list <- lapply(allProduce_split, function(sub)
    data.frame(product = sub$Category_Label[1],
               cor_produce = cor(sub$`Unit Retail`,
                                 sub$`Extended Quantity`)
               )
)

final_df <- do.call(rbind, unname(df_list))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
library(dplyr)



   df <-allProduce %>% group_by(Category Label) %>% mutate(correlation = cor(Unit Retail,Extended Quantity))
```